# Disable tab to display console commands in the Gremlin console

Tags: groovy, console, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am frequently copy-pasting some scripts to the Gremlin console that include tabs and as a result the gremlin console displays its commands for each of these tabs:

```
gremlin> 
:h           :help        :?           ?            :exit        :x           :q           :quit        :i           
import       :d           :display     :c           :clear       :S           :show        :inspect     :n           
:p           :purge       :e           :edit        :l           :load        .            :.           :s           
:save        :r           :record      :H           :history     :a           :alias       :rc          :register    
:D           :doc         :=           :set         :-           :uninstall   :+           :install     :pin         
:plugin      :rem         :remote      :>           :submit
```

Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to disable that behavior and a feature of the underlying Groovy Console which Gremlin inherits. The only work around I have is to configure your IDE to treat tabs as spaces.